# Why doesn't this simple MySQL subquery work?

Tags: mysql, sql

This query is virtually identical to the working example I was shown:

```
SELECT * FROM entities.entities
    WHERE entities.entities.id =
        (SELET MAX(entities.entities.id) FROM entities.entities);
```

This query was much simpler to begin with, but I've been adding database and table names everywhere just to be certain the query is impeccable.

It produces the not-so-helpful error:

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MAX(id) FROM entities)' at line 3

I've made sure I have MySQL version 5+, I've made sure the subquery is a scalar subquery, that is it returns only one column with one row, and is supported in the WHERE section of the query.

I see nothing wrong with it.

Enter the experts!

Comment: Other than the missing `C` in `SELET` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code should read:

```
SELECT * FROM entities.entities
WHERE entities.entities.id =
    (SELECT MAX(entities.entities.id) FROM entities.entities);
```

(You had misspelled "SELECT" as "SELET.")

Comment: Of all the simple and avoidable typos... SELECT? I've underestimated a good night's sleep.

Comment: Yeah, like we've never done that?  COUNTLESS times?  ;-)  There are rare occasions where copying and pasting (if possible) does help, this may have been one of them.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM entities.entities
    WHERE entities.entities.id =
        (SELECT MAX(entities.entities.id) FROM entities.entities);
```

Answer (score 1):

You mis-spelled select:

SELECT * FROM entities.entities
    WHERE entities.entities.id =
        (**SELECT** MAX(entities.entities.id) FROM entities.entities);

Answer (score 1):

Yeah Make sure to check your code first.

```
SELECT * FROM entities.entities
WHERE entities.entities.id =         
(SELECT MAX(entities.entities.id) FROM entities.entities);
```

SELET --> **SELECT**

Regards